# How to modify charts in Helm Stable repo

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

**What have I done:**
Added Stable repo into my helm and installed a chart(eg.: Redis, RabbitMQ/someapp).

```
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
helm install redis/rabbitMQ/someapp
```

**What do I need:**
Now I need to change the configurations of my chart(Redis/RabbitMQ/someapp).

1. How can I edit the chart to have a modified config for my app(Redis/Rabbitmq/someapp)?
2. Is it possible to edit the chart's config installed with Helm stable repo? or should I have to have my own repo to edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1.

To edit the chart, you need to copy the chart to some directory. Edit the chart as per your requirement. Go to the parent directory of the chart and perform the following command:

```
$ helm install <release-name> <chart-name>
```

It'll install your custom chart instead of the one from stable repository.

#### 2.

Yes, you can install charts from `stable` repository with custom `values.yaml`.

```
$ helm install --values custom_values.yaml <release-name> stable/<chart-name>
```

Comment: " you need to copy the chart" I can't find that chart. may I know the location pls? @kamol

Comment: You can find "official" Helm charts here: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable

Answer (score 6):

To pull a chart and check it locally just run

```
helm fetch stable/pgadmin --untar
```

This will put the chart in a local directory located in your working dir. You can then edit the chart from here, and do installation with

```
helm install <release_name> <chart_local_directory> -f your_values.yaml
```

Comment: i don't get your point @perkdaddy, can you elaborate it to match the question?